# SELECT MAX. По столбцу в базе не выводит цифру больше 9

Tags: php, sql

В столбце sale_id есть строка 10 и более, но почему то выводит 9. Когда меняю на поиск по другому любому другому столбцу выводит все верно максимальное число и трехзначное и более. Подскажи пожалуйста в чем может быть причина.

```
$q42 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT MAX(sale_id) AS max FROM sale ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$go42 = mysqli_fetch_row($q42);
var_dump($go42);
$a=$go42[0]+1;
echo $a;
```

Comment: Смею предположить, что `sale_id` у вас строкового типа, а не целочисленного, отсюда и преобладание значений с первым символом `9` над значениями с первым символом `1`

Comment: `$a, $q42, $go42` - пожалуйста, не надо так именовать переменные, а то зрение сразу -80

Comment: Агрегатная функция без группировки рассматривает набор записей как единую группу. Соответственно вопрос - вот нахрена для одной-единственной записи указывать сортировку и возврат только первой записи?